# Google Model Viewer Hide AR preview button when browser not support AR

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, quicklook, webxr, model-viewer

I'm using [google model viewer](https://modelviewer.dev/) lib. for AR support for an e-commerce site.

Custom button [View in you space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaNGC.png)

I want to hide AR preview button(View in your space) for those browsers who don't have capability of AR. and I also want to show custom "Add to cart" button which support "android" and "ios"?

[Add to cart button in AR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peuvg.png)

I add the code like the below ex. it's showing in android but not in ios

```
<model-viewer>
    <button>Add to cart</button>
</model-viewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the button apear in iOS you will have to add a usdz model using the ios-src parameter.

```
ios-src="/models/Astronaut.usdz"
```

You can also add quick-look to the ar-modes and have modelViewer try to auto generate a usdz model on the fly.

[ar-modes Docs](https://modelviewer.dev/docs/#entrydocs-augmentedreality-attributes-arModes)